# C# MVC - Login / SQL Security/Logins section

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am kind of new to this environment. What we want to do is to have the end user login with their Login name that is stored in the Security/Logins section. I am not sure where I can go to add this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name = variablename
```

any idea on where to go?

We are using Visual Studio 2013 / Framework 4.6 / SQL Server 2005

Comment: Sql Server 2005 has been fully end-of-life for several years now. That means it no longer gets any updates... not even critical security patches. Continuing to use this platform is dangerous and irresponsible, especially as the Express Editions of more recent releases is free.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this is what my company is using. So. Nothing I can do about that.

Comment: You can bring it up with your supervisor, to bring up with his, etc. There are actual serious known unpatched security vulnerabilities for this release of Sql Server.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that is my plan

Answer (score 0):

To log in with the SQL accounts you must build the provided username and password into the database connection string. If the user is able to successfully open an `SqlConnection` object, they can log in.

You'll have a saved connection string that looks something like this:

```
 Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;User ID={0};Password={1};
```

When the user tries to log in, you do something like this:

```
//pull this from web.config or similar
private string LoginCnString = "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;User ID={0};Password={1};";

public bool Login(string Username, string Password)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(string.Format(LoginCnString, Username, Password)))
    {
        try
        {
            cn.Open();

            //Login succeeds
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
           //Login fails
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You might *also* have a generic connection string you use for more of the mundane work of the application, but this is how you validate the login.

Comment: Like to add it in the Web.config in the configuration section? I already have the defaultconnection.

Comment: No. You have to build the connection string on the fly, incorporating the credential information supplied by the user.